# Compare and Match 2 Columns and Copy the values of Matched items from next Column in Workbook 1 to Empty Column in Workbook 2 against Matched items

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA Excel.

**Note:**

I have written this program for **2 separate sheets** but I have originally 2 separate workbooks and I want code to be written for **2 separate workbooks**.

**Question:**

In **Workbooks 1, Sheet name (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs)** I have 2 columns. **Column A contains Topic Information and In Column B I have the data related to the information.**

In **Workbook 2** I have **Column A** containing the Topic Information words some are similar to what I have in AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs Sheet and some are not and in Column B. I need values to be copied from Column B of Workbook 1 sheet (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs) on matching.

I want a macro in **Workbook 2 (Sheet 1)** that compares the values of Topic Information present in Column A with Topic Information Present in Column A of Workbook 1 Sheet (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs) and then copies the values from Column B of workbook 1 sheet (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs) to Column B of workbook 2 (Sheet 1) .

**My written code compares the words but when I add new row in Sheet 1 of Workbook 2 the values that are copied from Column B of Workbook 1 to workbook 2 Column B are not accurate.**

I need to compare 2 columns and copies the values of Column B of Workbook 1 Sheet (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs) to Column B of Workbook 2 (Sheet1) for the compared or matched words from Column A of both sheets.

Have a look at the figures below for detailed information.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim oldRow As Integer

Dim newRow As Integer

Dim i As Integer

i = 1

For oldRow = 1 To 1170

    For newRow = 1 To 1170

       If StrComp((Worksheets("AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs").Cells(oldRow, 1).Text), (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(newRow, 1).Text), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            i = oldRow
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = " "
            Else
          Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs").Cells(newRow, 2)
            i = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next newRow
Next oldRow

End Sub
```

1 WorkBook 1 Sheet (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs) Data
[image: WorkBook 1 Sheet (AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs) Data]

2 Workbook 2 (Sheet 1) Data
[image: Workbook 2 (Sheet 1) Data]

Example :

```
    Workbook 1          Sheet AQR Data      WorkBook 2         Sheet 1 
    Col A                  Col B            Col A               Col B
    Ford                   3                BMW                                                                         
    BMW                    4                Ford                                                        
    Jaguar                 5                Rolls Royce                                                       
    Rolls Royce            6                Jaguar
```

I have 2 Columns in workbooks.

I need a **macro in Workbook 2 Sheet 1** that will pick up the values likes BMW etc from **Column A** and match these values present in **Column A of Workbook 1 Sheet AQR** and the words which gets matched it copies the values of words like 3, 4 from **Column B of Workbook 1** to **Column B of Workbook 2** in front of Words.

In front of BMW I need Value like 4 so after matching words I need 4 in Col B of Workbook 2.

2. If no value is matched or new row is added in Workbook 2  which do not contain some word or value so it should be left empty and I need the values of matched words to be copied in front of respective words.

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated as i am stuck. Thanks in anticiaption.

Comment: To be precise: do you need 'vlookup' solution which will map data from one workbook to another? And 2 more questions: if particular row is not in the second file should it be added in the end?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "the values that are copied from Column B of Workbook 1 to workbook 2 Column B are not accurate."? Give an example of your code failure

Comment: @Rufus  Thanks a lot for your reply and questions . I have updated my Qurey according to your asked questions along with example I hope i remained able to explain my question to you.

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks a lot for your reply . Please have a look at the updated questions according to your asked question with example. I hope that i remained able to explain it to you. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @Rufus ,@user3598756 Can u help me in getting to the result.

Comment: Yes we can use Vlookup also but to be very honest I donot know how to match words with that.2nd Question Answer: No if particular row is not in the file so we donot add it at the end I only need the values of matched words that  are present in workbook2 sheet 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the line:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs").Cells(newRow, 2)
```

`newRow` variable is assigned to output, not to input loop - you should replace it with `oldRow` and it should work properly then.
You should also reverse the order of loops usage - you should use following logic (please see my Solution 1 example):

```
For newRow = 1 To 1170
    For oldRow = 1 To 1170
       ...
    Next oldRow
Next newRow
```

As if you find the result for particular value it may be replaced with " " in the next loop.

I have 3 additional remarks which don't affect the result but may impact efficiency:

1. You can also skip `i` variable as you can manage everything through variables used in loops.
2. You don't have to put output cell to " " everytime - with reversed order of loop you can do it before inner loop (I will show it in my example below).
3. Instead of putting fix max row in the loop, you can search for it - please refer to my example below, where I identify the value for `lrow_Input` and `lrow_Output` instead of using '1170'.

Please see below two examples of solution of matching from one Workbook to another:
Assumptions to both solutions:

1. WB_Input.xlsb is the file where you have 'AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs' worksheet and you want to match values from this WB (structure is as in your example - col A and col B to be used)
   [image]
2. WB_Output.xlsb is the file where you want to have the results in col B for values in col A:
   [image]
3. I don't know where you want to put your code (in Input or Output file that's why I put exact names of files - once you decide you can replace line assigning workbook to object (for example `Set WB_Input = Workbooks("WB_Input.xlsb")`) to assign it to `ThisWorkbook`.

Solution 1 is Your adjusted code:

```
Sub solution1()

Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim lrow_input As Integer, lrow_output As Integer 'variables indicating last fulfilled rows
Dim WB_Input As Workbook
Dim WB_Output As Workbook
Dim WS_Input As Worksheet
Dim WS_Output As Worksheet


Set WB_Input = Workbooks("WB_Input.xlsb")
Set WB_Output = Workbooks("WB_Output.xlsb")

Set WS_Input = WB_Input.Worksheets("AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs")
Set WS_Output = WB_Output.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS_Input
    lrow_input = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With WS_Output
    lrow_output = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For newRow = 1 To lrow_output

WS_Output.Cells(newRow, 2).Value = "" 'you clear cell only once, not during each search

    For oldRow = 1 To lrow_input
        If (StrComp((WS_Input.Cells(oldRow, 1).Value2), (WS_Output.Cells(newRow, 1).Value2), vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
           WS_Output.Cells(newRow, 2).Value = WS_Input.Cells(oldRow, 2).Value
           Exit For
        End If

    Next oldRow
Next newRow

End Sub
```

Solution 2 uses Excel formulas VLOOKUP and IFERROR in the way that code is putting formula to the first cell and copies it to all below (till last needed row). Then calculates it - in case auto calculations are disabled - and pastes results as values:

```
Sub solution2()

Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim lrow_output As Integer  'variable indicating last fulfilled row
Dim WB_Input As Workbook
Dim WB_Output As Workbook
Dim WS_Input As Worksheet
Dim WS_Output As Worksheet
Dim funcStr As String

Set WB_Input = Workbooks("WB_Input.xlsb")
Set WB_Output = Workbooks("WB_Output.xlsb")

Set WS_Input = WB_Input.Worksheets("AM_quote-overview_sales-inputs")
Set WS_Output = WB_Output.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS_Output
    lrow_output = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With WS_Input
    funcStr = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & "'[" & WB_Input.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(2)).Address & ",2,0),"""")"
End With


With WS_Output
    .Cells(1, 2).Formula = funcStr
    .Cells(1, 2).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    WS_Output.Calculate
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Please let me know if I understood your problem properly and provided correct solution - if not, please let me know which assumptions are wrong so I adjust it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . It worked great and sorry for a bit late reply as i was playing with the code. Thanks once again.